# c++ Assigning pointer in class data member

Tags: c++

I have a problem with c++.
I neet to do something like this

```
class MyClass 
{
private:
    MyType *T;
public:
    MyClass (const std::vector<std::string> &S)
    {
        MyType new_obj(S);
        T = &new_obj;
    }      
};
```

The problem is that my new object go out of scope at the end of constructor, so *T become a dangling pointer.
I can't do this:

```
MyClass (const std::vector<std::string> &S)
{
    T = MyType new_obj(S); 
}
```

because with new() we can only call the default constructor. If possible, i prefer to don't use the copy constructor of MyType

Sorry for bad english. Thank you very much, I whish you a nice day

Comment: Why do you think you can only use new with the default constructor?

Comment: How about `T = new MyType(S);`? Or even better `MyClass(std::vector<std::string> const &S) : T(new MyType(S)) {}` or even better use smart pointer for `T`.

Comment: Why is `T` a pointer in the first place?

Comment: "I need to do something like this"... No, you don't. Returning a reference (or a pointer) to a local variable invokes undefined behavior and/or flat-out logic errors, and will cause all sorts of fun later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because with new() we can only call the default constructor

Nonsense.

I believe the code you are looking for is something like this:

```
MyClass(const std::vector<std::string> &s)
  : T(new MyType(s))
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that you don't actually need a pointer, you just think you do. And the reason you think you do is because you aren't aware that you can call a constructor other than the default constructor for member objects. Well, you can, using the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).

```
class MyClass {
private:
    MyType T;
public:
    MyClass (const std::vector<std::string> &S)
        :T(S)
    {}
};
```

If I'm wrong in my assumptions, let me know, and I'll delete this answer.

Comment: Agreed, the pointer is only needed if there is any polymorphism required.